# how to atomically switch view controllers in a else if statement in swift 3

Tags: ios, swift, if-statement, swift3

Within the else part of a else if statement I would like the view controller to automatically switch to another view controller lets say "b". 
So this below is what I'm looking for.

```
if {
    stop.timer
} else {
    switch to b
}
```

what is the code to switch to b?

Thanks

Comment: Are you asking for a way to programmatically present new vc?

Comment: @Tj3n yes that is what I am trying to do.

Comment: This has been asked many times, do a google search first before create new question

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to move data from one view controller to another in Swift?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29309329/how-to-move-data-from-one-view-controller-to-another-in-swift)

Answer (score 0):

In your else statement

```
let nextViewController = self.storyboard?.instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("view") as! ViewController
self.navigationController?.pushViewController(nextViewController, animated:true)
```

Answer (score 0):

open your main.storyboard and provide the storyboard identifier(any name) for your viewcontroller in StoryboardID [image]

in your code .

if you want to Push

```
if {
    stop.timer
} else {
   let nextViewController = self.storyboard?.instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("VerifyUserVC") as! VerifyUserVC
self.navigationController?.pushViewController(nextViewController, animated:true)
}
```

and if you want to present Modally

```
if {
        stop.timer
    } else {
       let nextViewController = self.storyboard?.instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("VerifyUserVC") as! VerifyUserVC
    self.presentViewController(nextViewController, animated: true, completion: nil)
    }
```